# column "d" of relation "Drawings" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I don't know whats wrong with my query

```
UPDATE "Drawings" d SET
    d."IsMostRecent" = TRUE 
FROM (
    select distinct on (a."Code") a."Code", r."Id", a."DrawnAt"
    FROM (
          SELECT r2."Code" as "Code", max(r2."DrawnAt") as "DrawnAt"
          FROM "Drawings" r2
          GROUP BY r2."Code"
    ) a
    INNER JOIN "Drawings" r
    ON r."Code" = a."Code" AND r."DrawnAt" = a."DrawnAt"
    order by a."Code", r."Id" desc 
) AS d2
WHERE 
    d."Id" = d2."Id"
```

Error thrown: SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "d" of relation "Drawings" does not exist
Position: 27

Comment: instead of `d."IsMostRecent"=true` use `"IsMostRecent" = TRUE`. Also it is highly recommended to use small letter for identifiers otherwise it will make huge problem

Comment: @AkhileshMishra nice catch. it works great now

Comment: From the manual: Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target column — for example, UPDATE table_name SET table_name.col = 1 is invalid. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In update queries never use table alias with the column name in `set` section. You should write  `"IsMostRecent"=true` instead of`d."IsMostRecent" = TRUE`.

Suggestion: In postgres always use identifiers in small case. [wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names)